# How to add version notes to an app update on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I just updated my Android app, sending a new APK through the Google Play Developer Console (https://play.google.com/apps/publish) . I wanted to add some notes like "Added support for low-res screens" or "New soundtrack".

In Apple App Store, that's so easy. But I cannot find it in Google Play, so I'm feeling stupid. I also did some web search and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your [Android Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish)
2. Select your APP
3. Select the tab `Store Listing` if not selected

There you will find the option `Recent changes`

Comment: Great. Complementing, in portuguese, it'd be "Detalhes do aplicativo" / "Alterações recentes".

Comment: Glad that it helped. "De nada"